# HTML5 Audio player, make pause and play on time out

Tags: javascript, html

How do i edit this code below so that the activeSong.Play() will only occur for 10 seconds, then it will trigger the activeSong.pause() event

I have tried to code it but i thought it would be easier to post the clean code rather than my butchered attempt

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var activeSong;
    //Plays the song. Just pass the id of the audio element.
    function play(id){
        //Sets the active song to the song being played.  All other functions depend on this.
        activeSong = document.getElementById(id);
        //Plays the song defined in the audio tag.
        activeSong.play();

        //Calculates the starting percentage of the song.
        var percentageOfVolume = activeSong.volume / 1;
        var percentageOfVolumeMeter = document.getElementById('volumeMeter').offsetWidth * percentageOfVolume;

        //Fills out the volume status bar.
        document.getElementById('volumeStatus').style.width = Math.round(percentageOfVolumeSlider) + "px";
    }
    //Pauses the active song.
    function pause(){
        activeSong.pause();
    }
    //Does a switch of the play/pause with one button.
    function playPause(id){
        //Sets the active song since one of the functions could be play.
        activeSong = document.getElementById(id);
        //Checks to see if the song is paused, if it is, play it from where it left off otherwise pause it.
        if (activeSong.paused){
             activeSong.play();
        }else{
             activeSong.pause();
        }
    }

    //Updates the current time function so it reflects where the user is in the song.
    //This function is called whenever the time is updated.  This keeps the visual in sync with the actual time.
    function updateTime(){
        var currentSeconds = (Math.floor(activeSong.currentTime % 60) < 10 ? '0' : '') + Math.floor(activeSong.currentTime % 60);
        var currentMinutes = Math.floor(activeSong.currentTime / 60);
        //Sets the current song location compared to the song duration.
        document.getElementById('songTime').innerHTML = currentMinutes + ":" + currentSeconds + ' / ' + Math.floor(activeSong.duration / 60) + ":" + (Math.floor(activeSong.duration % 60) < 10 ? '0' : '') + Math.floor(activeSong.duration % 60);

        //Fills out the slider with the appropriate position.
        var percentageOfSong = (activeSong.currentTime/activeSong.duration);
        var percentageOfSlider = document.getElementById('songSlider').offsetWidth * percentageOfSong;

        //Updates the track progress div.
        document.getElementById('trackProgress').style.width = Math.round(percentageOfSlider) + "px";
    }
    function volumeUpdate(number){
        //Updates the volume of the track to a certain number.
        activeSong.volume = number / 100;
    }
    //Changes the volume up or down a specific number
    function changeVolume(number, direction){
        //Checks to see if the volume is at zero, if so it doesn't go any further.
        if(activeSong.volume >= 0 && direction == "down"){
            activeSong.volume = activeSong.volume - (number / 100);
        }
        //Checks to see if the volume is at one, if so it doesn't go any higher.
        if(activeSong.volume <= 1 && direction == "up"){
            activeSong.volume = activeSong.volume + (number / 100);
        }

        //Finds the percentage of the volume and sets the volume meter accordingly.
        var percentageOfVolume = activeSong.volume / 1;
        var percentageOfVolumeSlider = document.getElementById('volumeMeter').offsetWidth * percentageOfVolume;

        document.getElementById('volumeStatus').style.width = Math.round(percentageOfVolumeSlider) + "px";
    }
    //Sets the location of the song based off of the percentage of the slider clicked.
    function setLocation(percentage){
        activeSong.currentTime = activeSong.duration * percentage;
    }
    /*
    Gets the percentage of the click on the slider to set the song position accordingly.
    Source for Object event and offset: http://website-engineering.blogspot.com/2011/04/get-x-y-coordinates-relative-to-div-on.html
    */
    function setSongPosition(obj,e){
        //Gets the offset from the left so it gets the exact location.
        var songSliderWidth = obj.offsetWidth;
        var evtobj=window.event? event : e;
        clickLocation =  evtobj.layerX - obj.offsetLeft;

        var percentage = (clickLocation/songSliderWidth);
        //Sets the song location with the percentage.
        setLocation(percentage);
    }

    //Set's volume as a percentage of total volume based off of user click.
    function setVolume(percentage){
        activeSong.volume =  percentage;

        var percentageOfVolume = activeSong.volume / 1;
        var percentageOfVolumeSlider = document.getElementById('volumeMeter').offsetWidth * percentageOfVolume;

        document.getElementById('volumeStatus').style.width = Math.round(percentageOfVolumeSlider) + "px";
    }

    //Set's new volume id based off of the click on the volume bar.
    function setNewVolume(obj,e){
        var volumeSliderWidth = obj.offsetWidth;
        var evtobj = window.event? event: e;
        clickLocation = evtobj.layerX - obj.offsetLeft;

        var percentage = (clickLocation/volumeSliderWidth);
        setVolume(percentage);
    }
    //Stop song by setting the current time to 0 and pausing the song.
    function stopSong(){
        activeSong.currentTime = 0;
        activeSong.pause();
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: did you try setTimeout? like setTimeout(function(){ pause() },10) just after you are playing the audio

Comment: it just made it restart, for a reason i literally have no idea...i know it sounds dumb as the rest of this is more advanced, but a simpler timer would not function, will investigate.